# Laptop shuts down while on battery with no warning

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, asus-laptop

I have a Asus x53e laptop. For two months, the power fails while running, and it shuts down without warning. I have changed windows but the problem persists. I have opened my laptop  and had service done, but no result. The battery holds a 100% charge at the end of charging. After 45 min, anytime the power fails with no warning.

Comment: So if you are not charging the battery the laptop shutdowns after 45 minutes?  You need a new battery.

Comment: Just a guess: I've seen laptops do this when overheating because the fan was clogged with dust.

Comment: When the laptop was serviced, were the vents and CPU heatsink fans cleaned? Precisely what was done when serviced? And, what do you mean by "I have changed windows"?

Comment: Agree with Ramhound. AGAIN. New battery needed, especially when after powering back on external power battery shows 0-10% charge...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Power Options settings are not where you may want them to be.

Try going to: Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings and click the "Change advanced power options" button.  Then expand the "Battery" item and verify your various settings there.  If you have already done that, then add that to your post.  [image]Your percentages may be off.

Answer (score 0):

Which model number? There are many x53e laptops by Asus.

X53E-RH52, X53E-RH52BU, X53E-RH52RD, X53E-RH71, X53E-RH91, X53E-RS52... and they may not all come with the same battery,

In general, whether or not the battery *says* it has a full charge, it can be bad, or out of calibration. To find how long your battery runs, charge up the laptop, set it on a table or counter, and run a small script like this from a command prompt.

```
time /t > ran.txt
:top
dir /s | find "total"
time /t >> ran.txt
goto :top
```

This will loop around and add the current time each time it runs to a file named ran.txt - and when the laptop shuts down for lack of battery, then recharge the laptop, reboot, and compare the time at the top of ran.txt to the time at the end of ran.txt for the time your battery runs on what it thinks is a full charge.

The run-until-shutdown then full-recharge-before-power-up can recalibrate the battery's charging controller.  When it is fully charged, collect the start and end times, and then repeat the process to see if the charge cycle improved.

If it's still less than an hour, it's new battery time, for [product reviews of the low end i3 version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00739VG3G) of this laptop indicate a runtime of 3-4 hours.